# Is the "2038 bug" considered as a vulnerability? is it possible to exploit this?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability

Is it possible to use the "[2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)" on all kinds of systems / sites that use a calendar and similar features, in order to exploit a certain system in some way?

Comment: Possibly.  Any time a program doesn't behave as designed it's possible this could lead to a security vulnerability.  That in itself isn't a whole lot to go on, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "2038 bug" might be a vulnerability, but it fully depends on how the application you're attacking is coded.

Say, you have a web application that does this:

```
if ($todayTimestamp > $user['rightExpiresTimestamp']) {
    did('Not allowed');
}
```

So the user was granted access until, say, 2018 so it's now expired, because today's timestamp is about `1571325274` and is greater than `1514764800` which is 2018 timestamp.

Now, you wait until 2038 and the server is bug-prone. Then `$todayTimestamp` will overflow, and be interpreted as something like `-2147483648` which is lower than `1514764800` so access is not blocked.

Question is very broad tho, and will require 19 more waiting years to be exploitable in these (rare) cases...!

Comment: So, what if you change the system date to the future? Could you trigger this?

Comment: @schroeder I would say "yes", you can put the OS date to 2038 (exact date before bug) after disabling the automatic clock sync, and try. But maybe it will trigger other issues/canaries (ie maybe PHP or Java 32 bit has a built-in mechanism that throws in 2038 before reaching this application code)